# PhantomJS not making all AJAX calls each time page is loaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, phantomjs

I am trying to scrape [Purestorage Career page](http://www.purestorage.com/company/careers.html) to extract Greenhouse job listing. When I try loading page through PhantomJS, I sometimes see the full rendered page which contains Greenhouse job listing [job](https://boards.greenhouse.io/purestorage/jobs/142121) and sometimes I only get the partial rendered page which doesn't have greenhouse urls.

Seeing the page source of [Purestorage career page](http://www.purestorage.com/company/careers.html), I see the following code

```
<div class="container" data-component-name="embed-greenhouse" data-component-url="/api/jobs/v1/jobs.ws.json">

    <div id="alert-container" class="container">
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 results-col" id="greenhouse">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems like they are loading jobs by issuing a GET request to the [json url](http://www.purestorage.com/api/jobs/v1/jobs.ws.json). However, PhantomJS not ALWAYS make this request.

How can I make sure that all the AJAX calls are being made by PhantomJS. Is this happening because of the special code structure on this particular website?

Edit:
I am using Phantomjs 2.1.1. I also tried clearing cache before loading page but no luck.

```
page.clearMemoryCache();
```

Comment: Why use PhantomJS when you can simply call the API endpoint directly?

Comment: It is a more generic question. I crawl a lot of sites through PhantomJS and this particular case is not resulting data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue here. In this particular case, PhantomJS was treating page load as 'complete' even before the loading of async JSON file was done. Adding a delay of 1 sec after page load gives the script enough time to load Greenhouse data into the page.

Answer (score 0):

It is a cache issue, but you are right that PhantomJs 2.1.1 does not seem to respect the clearCache request.  The way I worked around this with [PhantomJsCloud.com](https://PhantomJsCloud.com) is to delete the on-disk cache and restart instances when a clear-cache request is made.